# How to calculate drag force vector

Tags: physics, projectile-motion

I am trying to calculate drag in 3D, and I came across the formula

$$F_d = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot C_d \cdot \rho \cdot v(t)^2 \cdot A$$

I understand how this formula is reached, as a proof is given here https://sciencing.com/how-to-calculate-drag-force-13710258.html.

However, that is for calculating the magnitude of the force, whereas I want to calculate it as a vector since $v(t)$ should also be a vector.

I stumbled across https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3fb8/577794f3eb802de98aadc06b0a1120a00c02.pdf, where it seems like they use the equation

$$F_d = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot C_d \cdot \rho \cdot v(t) \cdot |v(t)| \cdot A$$

Why does this work?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. "Why does this work"? Why does WHAT work? Are you confused by the fact that 
$$
v(t)^2
$$
was replaced by
$$
v(t) \cdot | v(t) |
$$? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @MattiP Yes I'm confused by it being replaced. I am using negative drag in my $\sum f = ma$ equation so I think that is sufficient?

Comment: If we want a vector version of the equation
$$\tag{1}
F_d = \frac{1}{2}C_d \rho v^2(t) A
$$
we need to modify the equation a bit. Equation ($1$) would give us a scalar. What if $v(t)$ is a vector, $v(t) = \vec{v}(t)$ ? This term is squared in the equation, and we want to have a vector equation that points in the same direction as $\vec{v}$. Therefore, the vector equation must be of the form
$$
F_d = \text{(a scalar multiplier)}~~ \vec{v}(t)
$$
...

Comment: @MattiP Okay but why $|v(t)|$?

Comment: (continuing)
The other condition is that the vector equation has to have the same magnitude as Equation ($1$). In other words, 
$$
\left| \frac{1}{2} C_d \rho v^2(t) A \right| = \left| (\text{a scalar multiplier})~~\vec{v}(t) \right|
$$
Do you see the solution approaching now?

Comment: @MattiP No I don't

Comment: (continuing) Evaluating the previous equation, we get
$$
\frac{1}{2} C_d \rho \left| v^2(t) \right| A = (\text{a scalar multiplier}) \left| \vec{v}(t) \right|
$$
Now we have to note that $\left| v^2(t) \right|  = \left| v(t) \right| \left| v(t) \right| $ and also that $\left| \vec{v}(t) \right| = \left|v(t) \right|$. If you plug these in, what do you get as a value for the scalar multiplier?

Comment: @MattiP $scalar = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot C_d \cdot \rho \cdot |v(t)| \cdot A$

Comment: Thus $F_d = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot C_d \cdot \rho \cdot v(t) \cdot |v(t)| \cdot A$

Comment: Wouldn't drag point in the direction opposite to the direction of motion though?

Answer (score 1):

To get the drag as a vector, just multiply $F_d$ with a unit vector pointing in the direction of the wind:
$$
\vec{F}_d = F_d \frac{\vec{v}}{|v|}
= \frac{1}{2} C_d \rho |v|^2 A \cdot \frac{\vec{v}}{|v|}
= \frac{1}{2} C_d \rho |v|\vec{v} A
.
$$

Comment: This is stating the obvious. No one debates the direction of drag or the magnitude of it. The question is what is the proper vector equation for drag? You all appealed to common sense to give the answer you already knew was right---but the OP had the common sense to do that, yet they refused to, because common sense fails. Science isn't built on common sense. And here the question is not "how can I write the drag force in a vector expression matching what I already know about the force direction".

Comment: @Alex. As I understand it, the OP accepts the equation $F_d = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot C_d \cdot \rho \cdot v(t)^2 \cdot A$ for the size, but does not understand why $F_d = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot C_d \cdot \rho \cdot v(t) \cdot |v(t)| \cdot A$ works for the vector. And the connection between these is just multiplication with the unit vector.

Comment: @Alex. Could you elaborate on how you interpret the OP's question?

Comment: Your answer just repeats the last part of the OP's question. By repeating what the OP clearly already knows, you answered nothing. The other answers are equally useless. What the OP wanted to know is why does the vector expression for drag---the one that he wrote down and the one that you repeated back to him/her---work. After all, it does seem an arbitrary convention to replace v^2 with |v|*v, and it's this that needs explanation. So the question is how do you arrive at |v|*v? And it's about vectors, and it's all properly explained in a similar question (see next comment for where).

Comment: For a proper answer to the OP's question, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205513/splitting-up-a-force-into-horizontal-and-vertical-components/205532

Comment: @Alex. You write "After all, it does seem an arbitrary convention to replace v^2 with |v|*v, and it's this that needs explanation" and that's what I explain. You earlier wrote "No one debates the direction of drag or the magnitude of it". So I take the magnitude and multiply with the direction: $\vec{F}_d = F_d \frac{\vec{v}}{|v|},$ and by simple algebra,
$$|v|^2 \cdot \frac{\vec{v}}{|v|} = \frac{|v|^2}{|v|} \vec{v} = |v| \vec{v}.$$